# Angular ng-pick-datetime make input field invisible

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am using ng-pick-datetime with datetime range with some input field and an datetime picker (calender) icon:

```
<div class="dl-date-time-picker">
    Date Time:    
          <input           
                [style.width]="'200px'"
                [(ngModel)]="dateTimeRange"
                (ngModelChange)="getrange($event)"
                [selectMode]="'range'"
                [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" 
                [owlDateTime]="dt">

          <span class="trigger" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
          </span>    
          <owl-date-time #dt></owl-date-time>        
</div>
```

[image]
It looks normally, and the calender item opens correctly aligned under the icon...

**But now, I would like to make the input field invisible for the user, and just offer the calender picker icon...**

I used `<input   type="hidden"`  and this works so far, the problem that I now have is, that the calender item opens on the far left side of my browser window... I don't know how to fix that problem:

[image]

How can I fix that problem, its too far left side...

Comment: As per show in image , I think you have to set it with help of css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the datetime picker needs the input field to determine the right position on the screen. You can hide the input via CSS, then it should work:

```
.dl-date-time-picker > input {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
```